# How to convert sine wave from an oscillator to TTL signal for microcontroller?

Tags: ttl, wave, sine

I tried to measure inductance by using a colpitts oscillator to generate sine wave. It works. I need to convert the sine wave to 5V square wave to feed to a microprocessor. The sine wave is coupled with a capacitor 0.47uF to eliminate the signal offset. The signal after the capacitor is zero crossing sinewave. When the signal connected to a zero-crossing detection comparator, I got problem. The zero- crossing sine wave drifts to about 10mV above 0 V. The output of the comparator is flat no square wave, since the input signal always higher than 0V. How should I do to avoid the signal drift, to convert the sine wave to TTL.
[image]

Comment: I like that circulating-current design ----- very localized ------ for excellent phase noise.

Answer (score 7):

> How should I do to avoid the signal drift, to convert the sine wave to
>   TTL.

You need to set DC voltage levels on both comparator inputs to (nominally) half supply rail. You can do this with a potential resistive divider on both inputs: -

[image]

For the input that connects to the capacitor use high value resistors to avoid low frequencies from your Colpitts oscillator being attenuated too much. Alternatively make a direct connection to the emitter and use a type of data slicer circuit like this: -

[image]

Your emitter connected sinewave is likely to be biased up sufficiently for the + comparator input and, R1 and C1 form a low pass filter to produce the same DC level on the other input but without significant AC signal content. Make R1 = 100 kohm and C1 = 1 uF - this will be OK down to frequencies as low as 10 Hz but if problems make C1 bigger.

You cannot expect an op-amp or comparator input to function correctly with just a capacitive connection AND you cannot expect (most) op-amps and comparators to work with an input connected to the supply rails.

Finally, it's a good idea (as pointed out in the comments) to add a pinch of hysteresis to prevent the output stuttering as the input crosses through the reference point. This is usually achieved by two resistors supplying a bit of positive feedback. Here's how you'd implement it for the data slicer type configuration (shown earlier): -

[image]

Comment: Best use some hysteresis, a "sharply tuned" comparator will turn something like a slow sine wave ... from an unshielded LC oscillator that likely will pick up mains hum and am radio ... into all kinds of jitter and errant pulses.

Comment: @rackandboneman yes, adding a small amount of hysteresis is a good idea. I shall footnote it into the answer.

Comment: Or a massive amount - I can only imagine a few hundred ways you might get unexpected frequency multiplication with that kind of inductance meter design ... Oh, and some overvoltage protection might also be a good idea with inductors of unknown Q factor...

Comment: It's a colpitts oscillator and shouldn't need over voltage protection.

Comment: Thanks Andy, The data slicer circuit is a very interesting idea. wondering if I can use single power supplyed (+5V only) comparator with the data slicer circuit. definitely I will use add hysterisis to my circuit. the frequencies of my application are 200KHz to a few Mega Hz. Is there any speciall concern  I should pay attention?

Comment: At a few MHz check that your comparator is fast enough - there's always the MAX999 that can easily handle many tens of MHz and has in-built hysteresis. The data slicer should work from a single 5 volt supply or even 3V3 for a MAX999.

Answer (score 5):

Turn your output OP-Amp into a Schmitt trigger by placing a positive feedback resistor between output and positive input. You can adjust the trigger levels by adjusting the feedback and input/ground resistors.